# How to set up Japanese keyboard with Google IME?

Tags: input-method

I couldn't find any good tutorials online that can guide me on how to set up a Japanese kana keyboard with Google IME. Most of the tutorials I found focused on setting up a romaji keyboard. But I want to learn how to type in kana.

For your reference, this is my keyboard

[image: .]

I'm not sure where to place the last two stickers. Can anyone help me with this thing?

Comment: This type of question if off-topic.  Please refer to our [resources](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) list.  It may have something helpful.

Comment: @istrasci I did. There's nothing useful.

Comment: [Google Image Search is your friend.](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+keyboard+layout&tbm=isch) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. This answer will serve as a future reference for anyone experiencing the same thing. If you are struggling to configure your kana keyboard mapping and Google IME's kana input mode doesn't work for you. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPzcp.jpg) shows the kana keyboard layout Google IME uses. Also, this [link](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1707/21/news021.html) might be helpful.